# Scrolling disappeared in angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an angular project that I want to make mobile.  I am trying to add Ionic to the application, but when I do, I can no longer scroll within the app.  I don't want to use any Ionic-specific components, I just want to build the app for android/ios.  I don't understand where my scrollbar went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your issue could be fixed by wrapping the content in `<ion-content>`.

However, since you don't want to use any Ionic specific codes, I recommend you wrap it in a `<div>` and just copy the predefined css of the ion-content, below link should help:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help you, but I had an app that scrolled on desktop browsers and not on some mobile and seemed to fix it by adding this to the css: 'overflow-y': 'scroll'.

Comment: I just gave this a shot and the scrollbar panel showed up, but there was no scrollbar itself, and I still couldn't actually scroll